# Losing custom #theme settings set in hook_field_widget_form after an error

Tags: 7, entities

I have defined a custom field in a custom module.  The new field applies a custom font to the options, and I have run into an issue with the widget form after an error. I have implemented hook_field_widget_form in a manner similar to the following:

```
mymodule_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {
    case 'mymodule_custom_widget':
      $element += array(
        '#theme' => 'mymodule_checkboxes',
      );
      break;
  }
  return $element;
}
```

mymodule_checkboxes and mymodule_checkbox have been defined in hook_theme as follows

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_checkboxes' => array('render element' => 'element'),

    'mymodule_checkbox' => array(
      'template' => 'mymodule_checkbox',
      'pattern' => 'mymodule_checkbox__',
      'arguments' => array('element' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

To put it shortly, `theme_mymodule_checkboxes` calls `theme(array('mymodule_checkbox'), array('element' => $current_element));` on every element in the `#options` array.

Everything is working great on the initial load of the form, the `theme_mymodule_checkboxes` function is called and the options are output using my custom template (the template isnt really necessary, I plan on replacing it with a theme function but havent gotten around to it. I don't think that particular oversite has any bearing on this issue but I may be wrong).  After I submit the form with an error - say I don't input a title or some such - the field is rendered using the default checkboxes theme.

Is there some hook I am missing in which I can define the default theme for the form widget before hook_field_widget_form?  One that hopefully fires even after a form fails validation?  I think I might be able to require a form rebuild in my custom field validation, but that forces extra work, and I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

This one turned out to be a fairly simple fix. I had `theme_mymodule_checkboxes` living in `mymodule.admin.inc` which was not being included on every page. Moving the function to the `mymodule.field.inc` which is specifically included in the module file caused the theme function to be included and fixed the error.

Many thanks to the drupal user Ayalon who found this fix.